# PHP var_export with double quotes

Tags: php, arrays

I have an array:

```
$a = array(
    "filterText" => "Search...",
    "filterNothingFoundMsg" => "NOTHING FOUND!",
);
```

When I do var_export it returns a single quotes around keys and values:

```
var_export($a);

array (
    'filterText' => 'Search..',
    'filterNothingFoundMsg' => 'NOTHING FOUND!'
);
```

How can I make it return in double quotes?

Comment: Why do you require double quotes? The two versions are equivalent for all intents and purposes.

Comment: What difference will it make?

Answer (score -1):

PHP has no way of knowing whether you used single or double quotes for keys and values. These strings are internal. The comparison shows that both representations provide identical arrays.

```
$a = array(
    "filterText" => "Search...",
    "filterNothingFoundMsg" => "NOTHING FOUND!",
);

$b = array (
    'filterText' => 'Search...',
    'filterNothingFoundMsg' => 'NOTHING FOUND!'
);

var_dump($a === $b); //bool(true)
```

var_export() should provide a representation with which the array can be reproduced. It does here.